# Advice needed for preventing file descriptor leaks in Raku

Tags: process, thread-safety, pipe, raku, file-descriptor

#### Background

A while ago I wrote a `Raku` [module](https://github.com/kjkuan/Shell-DSL) to test out some ideas I had for making external process pipelines (e.g., `grep raku | wc -l`). I followed the traditional way of creating `Pipes` and setting up `I/O` redirections for the external processes.

Since there's no `fork` available in `Raku`, nor is it recommended due to threads in `MoarVM`, I resorted to using `Proc::Async` to start a wrapper process for each external command in a pipeline, and the wrapper would then sets up `I/O` redirections to connect the command processes and the pipes, and then close other FDs before `exec`-ing the real command.

#### Problem

This all seems to work well except there's still the possibility that other parts of the program using the module might start a sub process (e.g., via `run`, `shell`, `Proc`, or `Proc::Async`) in another thread after the pipe `FDs` are created but before they are closed, thus leaking them and causing the command processes in the pipeline to block on `read / write`.

#### Question

How would you prevent `FDs` from leaking to any child processes started in another thread in `Raku`?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you use something like [`OO::Monitors`](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-monitors) to wrap the filehandles to prevent other threads from using it at the same time?

Comment: I think `OO::Monitors` prevents multiple threads from entering a method of an instance of that class at the same time. In my case, I have no control over what other parts of the system do; a program could be using some module that starts a thread that runs an external program via `Proc::Async` periodically, and I'll have no control over that.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "like". It's more or less the same concept. OO::Monitors creates monitors that are able to do that; you would need to encapsulate filehandles in that kind of thing to avoid them "leaking". Someone might still access them via memory, but that would be hard to do.

Comment: But that will only protect my module from leaking the FDs itself. I was wondering if there's a way to lock down the critical section of my module so that any attempts at forking the Raku process would be blocked until the FDs are closed. Hmm..., perhaps I can monkey patch `run`, `shell`, `Proc` and `Proc::Async` to make them acquire a lock that my module acquires for the critical section, assuming those are the only entrypoints in Raku that would create sub processes.

Comment: (My upvote is to signal it *sounds* like a good idea, not an affirmation that those four are the only routines/classes that need fiddling. Could a NativeCall lead to circumvention of such protection? Does that kibosh the idea?)

Comment: NativeCall can certainly circumvent the protection; however, given that using NativeCall to `fork` the Raku process is problematic to begin with, I wouldn't worry about it too much. I suspect monkey-patching `Proc::Async` might be enough.

Comment: A tangent. "Since there's no `fork` available in Raku, nor is it recommended due to threads in MoarVM". I'm not disagreeing, but are you aware that this works?: [`use nqp; my $i = nqp::fork(); say $i;`](https://glot.io/snippets/fxdkj6aqyc). See [A future for fork(2)](http://brrt-to-the-future.blogspot.com/2018/10/a-future-for-fork2.html).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I didn't know you can `fork` via `nqp`. I suppose it takes care of any problems one might have with calling the OS `fork` via nativecall? If so, then I might be able to use it to replace the hack of using `Proc::Async` + nativecall `exec` with just `nqp::fork` + nativecall `exec`. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: "takes care of any problems one might have with calling the OS `fork` via nativecall?" **No**. I urge you to read the article and contact Bart Wiegmans. His approach relies on ensuring there's only one system thread in use at the time the `fork` occurs: "force MoarVM into a single active thread even with multiple user threads active". However "that still leaves cleanup to deal with, after returning from `fork()` in the child process. Also, this will not work if a thread is blocked on NativeCall." Also: "abusing the GC in order to enable a `fork()` may be a bit over the edge of insanity :-)".